# Can dmesg print truncated lines in Linux?

Tags: linux, kernel

I am going to monitor dmesg by calling:

```
dmesg -c
```

every 1 second. I will look for specific strings in the output and then I will execute an action depending on the found strings.

However, I am worried about this scenario:

- The Kernel prints a 20-chars message into the dmesg ring buffer, for example:

  printk("Hello World !!!!!!!!"))
- Right when the Kernel is printing a specific char... let's say the 10th char, the user calls dmesg
- The last line was not completely written by the Kernel when we read the buffer

What will "dmesg -c" print?

a) A truncated line with only its first 10 chars (Hello Worl)

b) Omits the pending line

And then, in a next call of "dmesg -c", will it...

a) print the missing 10 chars of the pending line (d !!!!!!!!), or

b) print the full pending line?

This worries me because I will look for specific strings and if they get truncated then my idea will not work.

I am using Linux 2.6.31 and dmesg is run through busybox:

```
rwxrwxrwx  1 root   root       7 Jun  3 07:36 dmesg -> busybox
BusyBox v1.19.3 () multi-call binary.
Usage: dmesg [-c] [-n LEVEL] [-s SIZE]
```

I have run dmesg several times and I have never noticed a truncated line, but it's better to know if it has only been luck.

Thanks.

Comment: If you have a `syslogd` running, and it's logging kernel messages, you may find it easier to just monitor its output file (e.g. `tail -F /var/log/kern.log`).  Or configure the syslog daemon to do what you want - `rsyslog` has some pretty good recipes out there.

Comment: @TobySpeight Our kernel logs everything in /var/log/messages. The log is quite big and I'd prefer to grep a smaller input such as the cleaned dmesg output instead. We are running an embedded Linux. And also, I would make the same question about the messages file, could it include truncated lines?

Comment: What is logging your kernel messages to `/var/log/messages`?  If it's a reasonably modern syslog, then it should be able to copy a subset of messages to another file for you.  For example, my Debian systems have [`rsyslog`](http://www.rsyslog.com/),  which supports filtering on the message contents.  It also supports logging to database, so you could even use triggers if you wanted.